# How to limit my app to run only on OS 3.0 family (or earlier) and not on OS 4.0?

Tags: iphone, app-store, ios4

Is there any way I can limit my app on the store to say that is only compatible with 3.0 os family and not with 4.0 ? I've been searching on the store and all the requirements are only in the form "iOS3.0 or later". Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I just noticed that some apps on the store have a "ios4 verified" is there anyway for my app to say "ios4 not verified/tested"? I just want to optimize my app to ios4, but I just want to aware users about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, and Apple would never let you (besides, the vast majority of users will have upgraded within a few months, so you'd be artificially limiting your target audience.)

Why do you want to?

Comment: I just want to debbug and update my app to work correctly on os4. But in the meantime, somehow 'warn' users that the app is not tested, or optimized for ios4.

Comment: Then you'll have to do that before submitting. Apple *requires* all apps to be tested and working under iOS 4.0 now, and will reject any app that fails to run on it.

Comment: Then what's the problem you're having? You want to make the existing app unavailable to 4.0 users until you've tested a new version? Apple doesn't allow that. You'll have to either leave the current version accessible to 4.0 users, or remove the current version from the store until the new one is ready.

Comment: Yeah... seems like leaving it like that and hurry the bugfix and then updating the existent app is the right way. I only wanted to know if this limit-your-app-to-later-ios was possible.

Thanks dude.

Answer (score 2):

There is a high possibility that Apple will reject the app if it fails to run on OS 4.0. If you target App Store, then your app must run on OS 4.0. This does not mean that you have to use OS 4.0 features, you can ignore them if you want. But the app must not fail to run on OS 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I have an app approved and in the store.

I upgraded my phone to iOS4 and the dev app on the device stopped working - just crashed - a re-compile and install using the new SDK work fine (with a few changes that still need fixing).

This lead me to think I need to do what your suggesting - BUT:

A friend downloaded the same app (without upgrade) on his iOS4 phone and it works perfectly!

Seems Apple are making us think its totally broke so we fix it, without affecting the users experience (I guess through some sort of backwards simulation)

So, no sweat - just fix as soon as possible!